# Get versioning information of a DLL loaded through COM c++

Tags: c++, dll, com

I have an external DLL that has to be loaded as a CComPtr. It contains multiple interfaces but the content of these interfaces can change between versions of the DLL.

Is it possible to determine the version of the DLL that was loaded? After calling the CoCreateInstance the DLL then appears in Visual Studios 'Modules' tab (which contains the version), but I'm unsure how to get this information programmatically. AfxGetModuleState does not seem to contain any information about the DLL.

I've looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process but none of these appear to be the module/dll I am looking for.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hopefully someone knows a better way. But if not you could possibly approach it like I believe the debugger does when showing stack traces etc., even without pdb. On Windows / COM the `vtable` layout for virtual C++ methods is well defined (allowing other compilers, MSVC,GCC,Intel,etc. even languages to use them). Get the actual implementation address of a function and you can find which module owns that code segment (assuming no runtime code gen) using `VirtualQuery` and the `AllocationBase`.

Comment: If the author of the COM component did it right then there is no way to get that DLL loaded if you guessed at the wrong version since CoCreateInstance() and/or QueryInterface() won't work.  If he didn't do it right then only God can help you.  Hopefully he answers the phone.

Comment: If you have the CLSID handy, you might be able to look in the registry for the path, and then get the version number from the file on disk.